# Why was there a reference to the Battle of Hastings in Harper Lee's novel?

Tags: 20th-century, europe, north-america

I am unfamiliar with details of European history; how is the Battle of Hastings relevant to the historical background in Harper Lee's *To Kill A Mockingbird*?

Chapter 1, Paragraph 4:

> Being Southerners, it was a source of shame to some members of the family that we had no recorded ancestors on either side of the Battle of Hastings.

This passage is quite difficult for me to understand. How does the Battle of Hastings connect to the Southern American identity in Alabama during the 20th Century?

Comment: Southerners are renowned for the recorded depth of their family trees. This statement is making the point, with tongue solidly in cheek, that the family had no ancestors worthy of the name to trace genealogy to.

Comment: In the USA at least this is a historically important book of the mid to late 20th Century, and had an impact on the Civil Rights movement. Also, I'd argue the question is about what would be in the mind of an author in that same period when they said something like this. Its fairly recent history (I wasn't alive yet, but some of our readers were I'm sure), but I'd argue it IS still history.

Comment: This question is about why an author depicted a fictitious character using a long-ago historical event as part of their "frame of reference." This frame of reference is itself a historical "event" (actually, the ethos of a particular time and place). As such, the question is on topic. Put another way, It is about "the history of history." Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Southerners are renowned for the recorded depth of their family trees. This statement is making the point, with tongue solidly in cheek, that the family had no ancestors worthy of the name to trace genealogy to.

In practice it was much more common for Southern families to trace lineage to Civil War heroes,  Revolutionary War heroes, or notable early immigrant communities such as the Pilgrims of Mayflower fame. However, the further back the better, so to have no-one of note in one's lineage, all the back to 1066, was a significant hole in one's community standing.

Comment: One thing this answer undersells: While its true that Southerners got social status from being able to trace [their genealogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daughters_of_the_American_Revolution#Founding) back to the colonial period, and then to England, you were mostly socially OK if it ended there. Thus "back to the Battle of Hastings" is a wry exaggeration (or what the English might call "sarcasm").

Comment: @T.E.D.: I was thinking of *hyperbole* actually.

Comment: I was under the impression that wry hyperbole for humorous purposes was essentially how Brits do what they call sarcasm. But then again, as an American I'm [not an expert on these things](http://www.businessinsider.com/americans-dont-get-irony-2015-1).

Comment: @T.E.D.: I'm no Brit; I'm a half-Scotch, quarter-Dutch, quarter-Frisian Canadian.

Comment: This is hyperbole. An example of British  sarcasm - a woman invited to a Buckingham Palace garden party neglected to RSVP as required. When she apologised to an equerry, he replied with a smile "Oh, no, it was quite our fault for inviting you."

Comment: Pieter, you are making a mistake by characterizing this as unique to southerners.  My mother's family is from NJ/NY/NE and their habits of ancestry tracing resulted in a family tree being published in 1977 taking one branch of the family back to York (the one in England).  Plenty of blue bloods in the northeast, contemporary to the time of the novel, would be similarly inclined, to include friends of mine who have a lot of Dutch ancestry.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens Scotland is in Britain. It is part of the island of Great Britain and also part of the United Kingdom. If you are half-Scottish you are half-British, whatever your opinion of it.

Comment: @RedSonja: I am only rarely out-pedanted. Well done sir!

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens that's me channelling my Scottish grandfather ;-/

Comment: Forgive me for being pedantic. But I've been told that one is half "Scots," not "Scottish" or "Scotch."

Comment: @TomAu: "*Only in the past 150 years has a whisky usurped the name of a people.*"

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Don't tell that to e.g. "Mary, Queen of Scots." But otherwise a fair point.

Answer (score 3):

This character would have been a contemporary of Alabama's Governor [George Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Wallace) who (in) famously said, "segregation today, segregation tomorrow, segregation forever." This meant, "Your social status of today is your status of tomorrow, and forever." A person who shared that mindset would care deeply about whether their family had or didn't have ancestors going back "forever," (e.g. to the Battle of Hastings).

The Battle of Hastings was arguably the most important event in (modern) English history. Most prominent English families had men engaged in it on one side or the other. Not being "represented" in what as arguably the "creation" of modern England was a source of concern to lineage conscious English families.

After he won, William the Conqueror compiled a list of major landholders in the so-called [Domesday Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesday_Book). Most of these landowners, by definition, had some family member fight at Hastings because of the feudal system. Not having anyone in the family represented there after so many generations of intermarriage signified a lack of feudal ancestors with status, at least to some.

A commenter reasonably observed that "not everyone considers 950 years ago to be 'modern.'" That's the way that most people on Stack Exchange would feel. But the question was why did the author depict a character from the middle of the 20th century Alabama as using the Battle of Hastings as a "frame of reference." Put another way, the Battle of Hastings (almost 1000 years in the past) had relevance to Alabamans in the 1960s because those Alabamans believed that it had such relevance.

Southerners were more likely to feel this way than Northerners because a larger percentage of (white) Southerners were of English descent. Also, a larger percentage of English Southerners were "gentlemen" settlers, as opposed to e.g. Puritans, and therefore even more class conscious than other Englishmen.

Comment: You know, not everyone considers 950 years ago to be 'modern' :-)

Comment: @jamesqf: 1066 is "modern" in that no one since then successfully invaded England, not the Spanish, French, or Hitler, meaning that it was the last time that the ethnic composition of the British Isles changed--until recently.

Comment: Tom, see my comment to Pieter.  Your overstate the case considerably.

Comment: @Tom Au there was a little incident with the Dutch in 1688.

Comment: @RedSonja: William of Orange died without issue, and his influence on England was not as lasting as that of William the Conqueror.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: I didn't say that northerners didn't share this mindset. What I did say was that the South was more likely to produce a George Wallace (probably a distant descendant of William), and the extreme version of it.

Comment: @TomAu Successful oversaes invasions of England (1 temporarily, 2 sort of permanently, 2 very permanently) in 1139, 1216, 1471, 1488, 1688.  I count at least 5 since 1066.  No successful ones since 1688, though there were unsuccessful ones in 1715, 1745, and a very small one at some point in the 1790s.

Comment: @CMonsour: But none of them are as well remembered, or had the cultural impact of "1066." Which is the point. This is about "literature," not "history."

Comment: @TomAu It's a literary choice.  Hastings works well for Alabama.  I suspect Culloden or Marston Moor or Naseby would have worked better in other parts of the South (the first in Scottish-settled areas, the others in Virginia).